# Prevent Flutter app restart when changing locale using easy_localization with go_router

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I change the app locale by

```
      onChanged: (String? value) async {
        if (value != null) {
          await context.setLocale(Locale(value));
        }
      },
```

but it will restart the whole app, which is not what I want.

How to keep the same screen after I change the locale?

Thanks

PS.

I am using go router as follow:

```
MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: RouteGenerator.goRouterConfig(
          ),
          localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
          supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
          locale: context.locale,
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
        ),
```

It seems using `MaterialApp.router` will restart the whole app when setting locale.

I tried with traditional `Navigator.push` it works perfectly.
However, when I changed to use go router, it will restart the app.

I made a minimum reproducible code for your reference:

go router version, which will restart the whole app:

```
            MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: GoRouter(
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: '/lang',
                builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
                  body: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 500,
                        child: Column(children: [
                          DropdownButton(
                            value: context.locale.toString(),
                            items: const [
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: "en",
                                child: Text("English"),
                              ),
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: "zh",
                                child: Text("繁體中文"),
                              ),
                            ],
                            onChanged: (String? value) async {
                              if (value != null) {
                                await context.setLocale(Locale(value));
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                              onTap: () =>
                                  {},
                              child: Text("edit".tr()))
                        ])),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: '/',
                builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
                  body: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 500,
                        child: Column(children: [
                          InkWell(
                              onTap: () => context.go('/lang'),
                              child: Text("edit".tr()))
                        ])),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
          supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
          locale: context.locale,
        ),
```

without go router version, which will not restart the whole app:

```
MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
          supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
          locale: context.locale,
          home: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                                  body: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 500,
                                        child: Column(children: [
                                          DropdownButton(
                                            value: context.locale.toString(),
                                            items: const [
                                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: "en",
                                                child: Text("English"),
                                              ),
                                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: "zh",
                                                child: Text("繁體中文"),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                            onChanged: (String? value) async {
                                              if (value != null) {
                                                await context
                                                    .setLocale(Locale(value));
                                              }
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          InkWell(
                                              onTap: () => {},
                                              child: Text("edit".tr()))
                                        ])),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          child: Text("edit".tr()))
                    ])),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
```